# knex is building an invalid query

Tags: knex.js

I am new to knex. I am having difficulty with a migration. Inserting data seems to work well enough. However, when I try to query data within a migration I get an unexpected error.

This query:

```
await knex.select().from('account_types').where({ key: t.key }).first()
```

produces this error:

```
error: select (select *) from "public"."account_types" where "key" = $1 limit $2 - SELECT * with no tables specified is not valid
```

Obviously the generated query is invalid, but I have no idea why it's randomly inserting that "select *"

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use `first` and `select` at the same time, basically `first` should replace `select` if you only want to fetch a single result.

i.e. your query should be

```
await knex.from('account_types').where({ key: t.key }).first()
```